# Is there a way to select values from a column based on the comparison of another column with a subquery returning multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'll try to clarify the question in the title with an example,

You have a table `X`, this table contains the columns `foo VARCHAR` and `bar INT`
The values in the table are as following:

```
   TABLE X
-------------
| foo | bar |
-------------
| 'a' |  1  |
| 'a' |  2  |
| 'a' |  3  |
| 'b' |  1  |
| 'b' |  2  |
| 'c' |  1  |
-------------
```

And in order to simplify, we're going to take an example of what the subquery could return,
let's say `(1,2)`

What I would like to obtain using `(1,2)` is this :

```
----------
| result |
----------
|  'a'   |
|  'b'   |
----------
```

Because `a` and `b` are the only ones with `1` and `2` in the `bar` column.

**So basically, what I want to do is get all the `foo` values that have all the `bar` values returned by the subquery.**

However, I don't know if this is possible because I need to group multiple columns with the same `foo` and then compare their `bar` to the values returned by the subquery.

If you want to try yourself here is a Minimal Reproductive Example, you can go on https://sqliteonline.com/

*Make sure to use MySQL or MariaDB*

```sql
CREATE TABLE X (
    foo VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    bar INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (foo,bar)
);

INSERT INTO X(foo,bar) VALUES ('a', 1);
INSERT INTO X(foo,bar) VALUES ('a', 2);
INSERT INTO X(foo,bar) VALUES ('a', 3);
INSERT INTO X(foo,bar) VALUES ('b', 1);
INSERT INTO X(foo,bar) VALUES ('b', 2);
INSERT INTO X(foo,bar) VALUES ('c', 1);
```

You don't need to use a subquery, you can just assume that it's going to returned either `(1)`, `(1,2)`, `(2,3)`, `(1,2,3)` or every other combination (the order doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and filtering:

```
select foo
from x
where bar in (1, 2)
group by foo
having count(*) = 2;  -- number of items in the list of bars
```

You example data doesn't have duplicates.  But if it did, use `count(distinct bar) = 2` instead.

EDIT:

If you have a subquery, then use:

```
with s as (
      <subquery here>
     )
select foo
from x join
     s
     on s.bar = x.bar
group by foo
having count(*) = (select count(*) from s);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I replaced the `(1,2)` with my subquery and I had to duplicate it to do a COUNT in order to get the number of items in the list but it works exactly as intended.